# PHP arrays value insert to mysqli column

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm planning to insert the arrays value (inorder) to mysql table columns. I have 3 mysql table columns namely

1. first name
2. last name
3. serial number.

How can I do it.?  Here's my sql code(I have skip the other part):

```
foreach ($datas as $data){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $table(firstname, lastname,serialnum)
    VALUES ( data[0], data[1], data[2])";
}
```

Can someone pls help me

Comment: Where is query run code ?

Comment: Please also share your skipped part ? To fix the the problem.

Comment: you can't use `$sql = "INSERT INTO $table(firstname, lastname,serialnum) `part in the foreach loop like this . i think . this is wrong . you can concatinate , implode the values inside the loop .

Comment: show your `$datas` array . if you are using `data[0]` then i think no need to use foreach loop .

Comment: $datas array are row from table I get from other website using curl. @ShowStopper so I really need a foreach loop

Comment: It's too long bro. And there's no problem in the other code@Niklesh

Comment: can you show the format of `$datas` ??

Comment: and can you please tell what is the error/problem in this code??

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
foreach ($datas as $data){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $table(firstname, lastname,serialnum)
    VALUES ( '{$data[0]}', '{$data[1]}', '{$data[2]}')";
}
```

or try:

```
foreach ($datas as $data){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $table(firstname, lastname,serialnum)
    VALUES ( '".$data[0]."', '".$data[1]."', '".$data[2]."')";
}
```

Comment: @Niklesh he wrote in question that he skips other part of code

Answer (score -2):

```
foreach ($datas as $data){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $table(firstname, lastname,serialnum)
    VALUES ( '".data[0]."', '".data[1]."', '".data[2]."')";
   // mysql_query($sql);// write code for execute query by using mysqli_query($conn, $sql)
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing you're getting downvoted because of `mysql_query`. It's just a guess though

Comment: It will execute your query for every data.